# How to power 12V LEDs from a 12V AC power supply

Tags: electrical, lighting, wiring, outdoor

I have a 12V power supply that I am using to power some lights in my garden. I want to also power (in parallel) a set of 12V LED lights which (of course) require a 12V DC supply. Is there a simple method of AC->DC conversion that I can use? I am pretty handy at electonics so I could make a simple converter given the correct guidance.

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer at the [Electonics Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Possible dup on the EE site: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/515/how-to-convert-ac-to-dc

Comment: You need a [rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier).

Comment: actually, an LED is a rectifier, a diode. It will illumminate with 12VAC

Comment: @shirlock - Technically true, but LEDs can be fried by too high an opposite-polarity voltage ("reverse polarity breakdown"). Different LEDs have different tolerances, but 12V is too high for most, so at best these LEDs would have a shortened lifespan (and at worst they'd fry almost immediately.)  In addition, US AC cycles at 60Hz, which would produce an annoying flicker. For most people, the "flicker fusion rate" is about 75Hz.

Comment: I Tried one connected to the standard 12VAC and it worked - there was a slight flicker but it was hardly noticeable. I wouldn't want to shorten the life of the LEDs so would like to create a simple rectifier can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @ MT Head.  yes you are absolutely right, 60 HZ modulation can be a bit annoying, especially if it is sine wave instead of switched AC.  Was just saying it would work, maybe not well, but would work.

Comment: If you don't want the flicker, use two LEDs in parallel, with opposing polarity. Use two other non-light-emitting diodes with a higher breakdown voltage, one in series with each LED, to protect the LEDs.

Or instead of all of that, just get an actual rectifier -- Catalog #: 276-1146 will set you back $2 Radio Shack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to get all techy on you, but to do what you want to do with a 12 vac power supply, you will need a bridge rectifier. Besides converting to 12vdc, you need to fill the 60 hz reverse polarity portion of the AC wave. This requires a voltage divider, then reassemble the two rectified polarity sections into one same, continuous polarity voltage source.  Keep in mind, if the AC source is sine wave AC, not switched AC, the DC result will only be apx 70% of the AC peak to peak voltage, or 17 vdc.  Think the geeks at electronics exchange may have a simple circuit  they could share with you. Realistically, since the Led lights probably have such a small amp draw, you probably could pick up a 24VDC power supply for cheap money online or maybe even your local Radio Shack, and save your self a lot of hassle.

Comment: I already have a power supply for the lights but I have the ac supply drilled through the wall with a dusk to dawn sensor fitted so wanted to use all of this. Will post on electronics for a simple rectifier.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rectifier is 4 diodes one from each AC line to the positive input of the LED and two from the negative output of the LED to each of the AC lines. (4) 1N4007  diodes will do just fine for this.  Just wire two up together on one end and the other two the opposite way like and in and out Y and attach to each end of the diode(s) the other ends mate up from each Y to the AC lines.  if it doesn't work reverse the diode connection cause you probably hooked up positive to negative and vice-versa.

google  "rectifier circuit" for a diagram

Answer (score 0):

I built a lofted bed for my son and put on some deck lights that shine just enough light down at night to illuminate the area.  I just bought an adjustable DC power supply at Walmart...one of those replacement sets you can buy to replace some AC-DC transformer that got lost or burned out...it comes with multiple female ends, and can switch both the voltages and polarity.  I just bought one of those and converted 120VAC down to 6VDC (I think 12V was too bright).  It works great...is simple, and cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Diode in reverse parallel with Led (or Led with limiting resistor).  Should give you a halfwave rectified 60hz sine & the Led will still light up, but some people might notice said flicker. You might compensate the flicker by evening out sinewave with simple RC.  Might be all simpler than a bridge rectifier circuit.

Answer (score -1):

It is required an 12VAC to 12VDC converter, Not a simply bridge circuit, because the 12VAC will become about 17VDC after bridge circuit at no load condition, that will damage your lighting, but at full load condition, the voltage will be draw to a very low level that will not able to light up the LED,
So it is required an high efficiency PWM regulation circuit, such as an DC-DC converter design, but with AC input, you can look at here, there are a 84W 12VAC to 12VDC adapter:
http://www.enersystec.com/sdp/1045530/4/pd-5076639/12433566-2210481/12VAC_to_12VDC_Converter_Power_Supply_Adapter.html